# Should we merge [message-driven-bean] and [mdb]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Tags [message-driven-bean](/questions/tagged/message-driven-bean) and [mdb](/questions/tagged/mdb) seem to be the same thing. What about merging them?

Comment: [tag:mdb] is now a synonym of [tag:ms-access].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They can't be merged, but they do need to be cleaned up.  [mdb](/questions/tagged/mdb) can (and often does) refer to an Access database file.  I think that should be the canonical meaning for that tag, and [message-driven-bean](/questions/tagged/message-driven-bean) should stay.

Comment: "They can't" because they're use for two purposes?

Comment: @genesis-φ Yes, because "mdb" has two valid meanings on the site, they should be separated instead of merged.

Comment: okay, that seems fair